# Objective-C: Returning int to BOOL method

Tags: objective-c, methods, integer, boolean

I am new to Objective-C and i wonder why this method compiles, can anyone explain me why?

Thank you

```
-(BOOL) isEnabled{
   return 56;
}
```

Comment: There's an implicit cast - the last line is effectively: `return (BOOL)56;`.

Comment: I knew you would ask that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `BOOL` in Objective-C is a `typedef` of `signed char`. Since `56` fits in that type, the implicit conversion from a literal `int` results in no data loss.

Comment: Zillan, also note that that this may break code if it relies on a `YES` or `NO` value. E.g. `if([self isEnabled] == YES]` would fail while `if([self isEnabled])` would work.

Comment: Yep, which is why normal coding style avoids comparing against those constants, and only uses them for assignment.

Comment: You should really check out this article: http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/564-bools-sharp-corners/

Answer (score 0):

You can think of a BOOL in objective-c as

```
false === 0 === nil   //Anything that is zero or nil is false
true = !false         //Anything that is NOT zero or nil is true.
```

56 therefore returns true because it is not zero

Comment: No it isn't. A BOOL in Objective-C is a `signed char`.

Comment: My "definition" was a bit misleading, I've amended.

Comment: but `NSLog(@"%d",[self isenabled]);` returns `56`. Isn't that weird?

Comment: No, it's expected. `56` fits in `signed char`.

Comment: Mathematically a boolean is true or false, but in objective c, your boolean can store a number of values. Zero values are treated as false. Non-zero values are true with the exception of multiples of 256 as I've added to my answer.

Comment: Its not actually a boolean type, @JamesWebster. It's still an (in most C implementations) 8-bit ***signed*** integral value. You may be confusing `BOOL` with the 2-value C99 `_Bool` or C++ `bool` types, but they are not equivalent.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan What in my answer suggests I think it's a 2-value type?

Comment: The entirety of your answer suggests that.

Comment: 'Be aware that since the unsigned char is limited 0-255' means that there are 256 values.

Comment: Wrong, but not 2 values. I've removed the extraneous information as it's making the answer convoluted.

Comment: The `BOOL` type is actually broken.  In C, non zero integers are considered to be true but `(BOOL) (x * 256)` where x is an integer is false because the typecast discards all the non zero bits.